# Using a text file as pattern for preg_match_all php

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match-all

hey I'm making a word sensor for a school project and i cant seem to get the preg_match to filter characters suck as $,%,*,1-9 and other special characters  i've tried \w,\W,[W]+ but none of the following seemed to work

```
$lines=array();
  $fp=fopen('Bad.txt', 'r');
  while (!feof($fp))
  {
    $line=fgets($fp);
    //process line however you like
    $line=trim($line);
    //add to array
    $lines[]=$line;
  }
    fclose($fp);
    $string = Input::get('comments');
    $matches = array();
    $matchFound = preg_match_all(
      "/\b(" . implode($lines,"|") . ")\b/i", 
            $string, 
            $matches
          );
    if ($matchFound) {
      $this->addError("The following is not allowed please change it.");
      $words = array_unique($matches[0]);
      foreach($words as $word) {
        echo "<li>" . $word . "</li>";
      }
      echo "</ul>";
    }
```

Comment: obligatory comment on how swear word sensors don't actully work. REF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordfilter and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Comment: Your `implode` call is backwards. Try `implode('|',$lines)`

Comment: that didnt effect the code